# Parsing XML in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I am creating an IOS app , I have to read the Rss feeds from the specified url and Display only the specified contents ti the user , how do i parse the XML contents ? Is there any similar API to JSoup present in Xcode ?

Comment: Take a look at Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the `NSXMLParser` class information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the TBXMLParser:  https://github.com/71squared/TBXML .
It's a light-weight XML parser designed for iOS. 
However, you can check in http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project the different options you have depending on the type of document you're planning to parse.